# Python - I'm getting an indentation error, but I don't see one. Tabs and spaces aren't mixed

Tags: python, indentation

My code is:

```
90              if needinexam > 100:
91                  print "We are sorry, but you are unable to get an A* in this class."
92              else:
93                  print "You need " + final + "% in your Unit 3 controlled assessment to get an A*"
94          
95          elif unit2Done == "n":
96              
97          else:
98              print "Sorry. That's not a valid answer."
```

and the error is:

```
line 97
    else:
       ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

I have absolutely no idea why I'm getting this error, but maybe you guys can help me. There are A LOT of if/else/elif statements around it so that may be confusing me. Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

EDIT:
Adding "pass" or code into the elif statement just moves the same error to line 95.

Comment: We probably need more context, for example the `if` matching the `elif`, to be able to spot the error.

Comment: use a texteditor that knows about python indentation (or at the very least can show you the indentation characters used)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this:

```
elif unit2Done == "n":
    pass # this is used as a placeholder, so the condition's body isn't empty
else:
    print "Sorry. That's not a valid answer."
```

The problem here is that the body of the `unit2Done == "n"` condition can not be empty. In this case, a `pass` must be used as a kind of placeholder.

Comment: I thought that could be the problem, so I added a print statement in there. But that just gives me the same indentation error, but on the elif on line 95. Thank you though.

Comment: @CalCourtney then it's quite possible that indeed this is an indentation problem. Use a good text editor, copy the whole text in it, and make sure to replace all leading white space to either spaces or tabs, without mixing them

Comment: I use TextMate exclusively and I've just check every single line of code and they are all tabs. It's a very confusing problem o.O

Comment: @CalCourtney then it's possible that some of the conditions are not aligned at the right level, I can only speculate this because the code in the question is only a fragment.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from requiring `pass`, it's right here:

```
95          elif unit2Done == "n":  # space space tab tab
96              pass # space space space space tab tab tab
97          else: # space space space space tab tab
98              print "Sorry. That's not a valid answer." # space space tab tab tab
```

You do have a mixture.

In vim, you can do this:

```
set listchars=tab:>-,trail:.
```

And this is what your code looks like:

```
95  >--->---elif unit2Done == "n":
96    >->--->---pass
97    >->---else:
98  >--->--->---print "Sorry. That's not a valid answer."
```

Comment: @CalCourtney I copy/pasted the code in your question, so I'm _very_ surprised you're not getting an `IndentationError` there...

Comment: I think it's a problem from when I input it into the question. It's my first question, so it's probably not correct. In TextMate, there are no spaces or tabs after each line. Thank you very much though.